# Ajax request in Drupal gives 403

Tags: php, jquery, ajax, drupal, http-status-code-403

I am doing an Ajax request in Drupal. I´m making a POST request to a custom PHP file that will zip the files. But when i send an array of long filenames i get an error message in the console;

```
POST http://www.example.com/url/zip-file.php 403 (Forbidden)
```

My Post request looks like this:

```
files_array[]:/long_url/really%20long%20filename.pdf
files_array[]:/long_url/really%20long%20filename.pdf
files_array[]:/long_url/really%20long%20filename.pdf
files_array[]:/long_url/really%20long%20filename.pdf
files_array[]:/long_url/really%20long%20filename.pdf
```

It works with a few file names, but as i add more, the 403 error comes up and my function fails.

Does anyone have a clue of what it might be?

I have these values in my .htaccess file

```
php_value upload_max_filesize 200M
php_value post_max_size 200M
php_value memory_limit 200M
php_value max_input_vars 2500
```

And i have checked phpinfo() to make sure they are working

The javascript request looks like this:

```
$.ajax({
    type: 'POST',
    url: Drupal.settings.basePath + Drupal.settings.pathToTheme + '/includes/zip-file.php',
    data: {
        'files_array': files_array
    },
    success: function(data) {
        var result = JSON.parse(data);

        files_array = [];
        if(result.success) {
            window.location.href = Drupal.settings.basePath + result.file_path;
        } else {
            alert('Failed to create zip file.');
        }
        $('#table-actions').find('.ajax-load').hide();
    }
})
```

Edit: i have also tried to completely empty the PHP file to make sure it is not a PHP error (as far as i understand).

Answer (score 1):

1. First I will explain what the `Forbidden 403` means following the [wiki](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/HTTP_403) page:

   - A web server may return a `HTTP 403 Forbidden` status in response to a `request` from a `client` for a web page or it may indicate that the server can be reached and process the request but `refuses` to take any further action. `HTTP status code 403` responses are the result of the web server being configured to deny access to the requested resource by the client.
   - A common request that may result in a `403 Forbidden response` is a `HTTP GET request` for a web page performed by a web browser to retrieve the page for display to a user in a browser window. The web server may return a 403 Forbidden status for other types of requests as well.

---

2. Reason why you might get the `403` status:

   - It might be because you didn't define a `page callback` attribute, for this you can check the documentation of `hook_menu()` [here](https://api.drupal.org/api/drupal/modules!system!system.api.php/function/hook_menu/7.x). If a parent doesn't exist for the menu item in question, it returns an `Access denied`. This happens even before the current user's access to your menu item is resolved; so the `access callback` doesn't really matter.

---

3. A **solution** might be:

   - Adding this to the `ajax post`:

     > 'access callback' => 'user_access',
   - Downgrade your `Jquery` **in your admin theme**.
   - If none of these solutions work you might want to have a look [here](https://www.drupal.org/node/2541722).

Comment: Huge thanks for your detailed answer! :)
Sorry if i am a bit slow. Exactly where should i be adding 'access callback' => 'user_access'?

Comment: @superhenke put it below the `type`, plus it `could` be a solution, not 100% guaranteed, but hope they help out of course.

Comment: Okay, i get it. I will test this on monday. Thanks again for your help. I´ll remember to check your answer as correct if it works!

Comment: @superhenke no probelm :) hope it will help you out.

Comment: @KingReload I am getting ajax error 403 when I am trying to index profile2 data with searchapi. I removed the server and added again and re-enabled. Then I tried to index 1 item. Then I downgraded my jquery to 1.4. Nothing worked. Before I apply the patch in the link, I want to know whether there is another  solution?

Comment: @Umair a 403 is a bad request error, meaning you have insufficient permissions? Maybe you forgot to include the api key / secret / csrf_token as header?

Comment: @KingReload What sorry? api key? I have a website on pantheon. I am not using any custom code. Simple search api module with dbserver. Let me know if I am missing anything

Comment: @Umair my bad, was wrapped up in my own thoughts, so I read the question wrong. Also making a seperate question would be better

Comment: @KingReload Posted https://drupal.stackexchange.com/questions/257687/ajax-error-403-when-trying-to-index-with-search-api

Answer (score 1):

It turned out to be our ModSecurity firefall that blocked the POST requests. My host helped me to resolve it.